# Ejecutar una funcion al momento que se crea una ventana en Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy creando una ventana en Tkinter que al cambiar la seleccion de un ComboBox (que contiene lista de unidades de medicion) se actualice los Label de dicha ventana (que tienen nombre de un elemento el cual tiene unidades). Esto lo desarrolle con el metodo "bind" y funciona muy bien.
Sin embargo, deseo que la funcion asociada con el evento "ComboboxSelected" se ejecute tambien cuando se construye la ventana, ya que los textos en los Label deben cargarse con la informacion correcta cuando se abre la ventana (porque paso las unidades en las que arranca el programa). Sin embargo, cuando llamo la funcion de manera directa sin estar asociada a un evento ya sea con "command=" o con el metodo "bind" me sale un error:

```
NameError: cannot access free variable 'desplegableUnidades' where it is not associated with a value in enclosing scope
```

Imagino que siempre debo asociar la funcion con algun evento de la ventana. ¿ existe un evento tipo "bind" como "ComboboxSelected" a algun Widget que se ejecute cuando se construya el Widget?. Necesito correr la funcion antes que el usuario haga cualquier cosa en la ventana.

Gracias.

PD: no ingrese el codigo que tengo porque son mcuhas lineas y esta una pregunta es muy general

Comment: Hola Andrés, no es necesario que agregues todo tu código, solo aquello que sea relevante para poder ayudarte, si no quieres que tu pregunta sea cerrada, editala, y agrega lo que tienes. de paso mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0):

En realidad, lo que buscas es llamar a una función cuando el valor del ttk.Combobox cambia. El problema es que el evento ComboboxSelected, como dice su nombre, solo captura el evento en el cual el usuario elige un valor en el combobox.

#### Propuesta

Lo que podés hacer para detectar este cambio es usar una variable de control. El plan sería crear una variable de control, asociar una función a cuando la variable es escrita y asociar esa variable al combobox. Al ser asociada al combobox, tanto la variable como el contenido del combobox se sincronizan.

Recuerda que es obligatorio para el correcto funcionamiento que establezcas el valor de la variable **despues** de haber asociado la función, ya que si no la función no estará asociada a la variable cuando hagas dicho cambio.

#### Demostración

A continuación, hice un código con un combobox que tiene las opciones "hola" y "mundo" y un Label que almacena la primera letra de la opción seleccionada:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Cuando se llame a la función, recibirá 3 argumentos a los que no les daremos uso
def update_label(*args):
    label["text"] = valor_combo.get()[0]

root = tk.Tk()

valor_combo = tk.StringVar()
valor_combo.trace_add("write", update_label)

combo = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=valor_combo, values=["hola", "mundo"])
combo.pack()

label = ttk.Label(root)
label.pack()

combo.current(0)

root.mainloop()
```

Que produce:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez asociada la función, el Label cambiará tanto por una modificación programatica del valor como por un evento del usuario.